# Limits on integral for marginal distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I want to find the marginal distribution of $y$ for a joint distribution $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. It is bounded for $0<x<1$ and $-x<y<x$, which is the bit I am struggling to get my head around. Is it okay to do $\int_{y}^{1} f_{X,Y}(x, y) \,dx$ $+$ $\int_{-y}^{1} f_{X,Y}(x, y) \,dx$ for the marginal pdf of $y$ (which you get from looking at the graph)? Or do I need to do it individually, thus yielding a piecewise marginal distribution for $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the relevant region:

[image]

If you're marginalizing over a specific value of $x$, then you integrate from $-x < y < x$.

Comment: Sorry, but I’m still not getting it. I suppose the essence of my question is that I don’t know whether the marginal distribution of y should be piecewise or not, so don’t know whether or not I should add the two integrals I named. Thanks in advance

Comment: No.  Not piecewise.